# An image view on an Image View xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an app using Xcode 8.1 and and swift 3.0.

Using storyboard I've expanded an image view to take up the whole view and set a picture to it to be used as a background image (using self.view.background doesn'[image]t give the image the same layout).

This works. I have defined the constraints for it plus added 2 textboxes and a button that also have constraints.

Now I try to add a new image on top of the background image, but then I cannot define the constraints for the front-most image view. I get something like this with two errors telling me to define the constraints but when I do nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it looks you as per the screenshot, you should just give the padding (spacing to nearest neighbour) for left , right and top in your storyboard.

If there are any warnings just set the current constraints to supersede other views. This can be achieved by selecting the warning and then update constraints and check the box apply to all views in container. It should work.

Comment: Yep, turns out there was an element too close it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to pin the imageView, what constraints have you set so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the constraints for the front image view (as on the your screenshot as well). I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 0):

have you set below constrains
1. Top Layout
2. Bottom layout
3. Leading
4. trailiing
5. height

or 
horizontal in center
vertical in center